# passing php session variable to a php page in another ip through hyperlink

Tags: php, html, session, session-variables

I want to pass session variables, a username and a password, to another php page when clicked on a hyper link. when i give the code like below, the variables  will pass the to needed page.

```
<a href="http://localhost/vtigercrm/">Customer Relationship Management</a>
```

But when i changed it to specify an ip address as below  (so that everyone can use it), the session variables are not passing to needed page.

```
<a href="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/vtigercrm/">Customer Relationship Management</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one will be able to "help you" if you dont specify _how_ you pass those values...

Comment: Are those two pages supposed to be on the same server, or entirely different servers?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  most sites use cookies to manage session keys.  Cookies won't be passed to a completely new domain.   You will have to either append the session key to your url, or do a post request with the session key as a post variable.

Comment: but i can't pass the details such as password along with the url, it will be visible to everyone . how can i avoid that situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can't share it between differents servers.

Answer (score 0):

That's right. Another domain, another cookies, another session id cookie, another session.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

on site 1:

```
<a href="http://localhost/vtigercrm/index.php?si=<?php echo session_id; ?>">Customer Relationship Management</a>
```

in site 2:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_id($_GET['si']);
?>
```

Comment: but i can't pass the details such as password along with the url, it will be visible to everyone . how can i avoid that situation?

Comment: use an form, with the username and password and session id in an hidden field then. and when an user clicks the button, the user will go to site 2, and than you get the session id, set it, and do stuff with username and pass